# Cinnamon vs. "System Settings" duplicate shorcut setting modules?

Tags: gnome, linux-mint, cinnamon

I'm running Linux Mint 14 with Cinnamon. I want to change some keyboard shortcuts, so I type "keyboard" in the search bar, and the "System Settings" -> All -> Keyboard menu shows up.

However, if I open "Cinnamon Settings" (a separate executable) -> Keyboard Shortcuts, I see a similar keyboard shortcuts menu. Except, not all of the shortcuts are the same between the two.

Why are there two different places to set keyboard shortcuts? Is there a preferred way that I should set them? What happens if the conflict each other?